# Jupyter Notebook: File ".ipynb_checkpoints" does not exist - Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

my code looks like this:

```
os.chdir('/media/data2/jupyter_notebooks/sacherr/Daten')

i=1
for f in os.listdir():
    mdf = MDF(f)
    df = mdf.export('pandas')
print(i)
i=i+1
```

and i always get this error code:

```
MdfException: File ".ipynb_checkpoints" does not exist
```

how can i get around this?

Thank you,
R

Comment: have you installed jupyter notebooks correctly?

Comment: till now everything worked, I first got this error when i tried to work with the for loop to read different mf4 files from this directory given up there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following: The MDF constructor needs the full path of the file. But `os.listdir()` only gives you the filenames. Try adding the path to the dir to your `f` variable.

I got this idea from the [MDF source code](https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.2/_modules/asammdf/mdf.html):

```
    def __init__(self, name=None, memory='full', version='4.10', **kwargs):
    if name:
        memory = validate_memory_argument(memory)
        if is_file_like(name):
            file_stream = name
        else:
            if os.path.isfile(name):
                file_stream = open(name, 'rb')
            else:
                raise MdfException('File "{}" does not exist'.format(name))
        file_stream.seek(0)
```

like that:

```
i=1
for f in os.listdir('/media/data2/jupyter_notebooks/sacherr/Daten/'):
    f = '/media/data2/jupyter_notebooks/sacherr/Daten/'+f
    mdf = MDF(f)
    df = mdf.export('pandas')
print(i)
i=i+1
```

Comment: thank you sharku. I don't understand how to implement this in my     f variable? can you give me an example?

Comment: @raffa_sa Done!

Comment: i tried but then it adds the path to the name. My error now  MdfException: File "/media/data2/jupyter_notebooks/sacherr/Daten213-2047_20170524200454_66T_bearbeitet.mf4" does not exist

Comment: sorry my mistake a forgot a / after Daten

Comment: i implemented this but i still get the same error message MdfException: File "/media/data2/jupyter_notebooks/sacherr/Daten/.ipynb_checkpoints" does not exist

Comment: my .ipynb and my files i want to get trough the for loop are not in the same directory. But if i throw them in one directory my for loop would also try to get the .ipynb file which isn't rigth. do you think the problem is that the .ipynb file is not in the same directory?

Comment: it is good that they are not in the same directory. Somehow the path you gave as working directory and the one that is used for listing the files are not he same... I gave the path now directly to the os.lisdir()  perhaps that solves it.